# best way to convert column to json array (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

What the best way to union column's data to json Array?

I have the table

```
Foreign_ID | Primary_ID | Position | Name

143         2344        Postman     Ann
143         2345        Postman     Tim
144         2346        Postman     Bob
144         2347        Postman     Dan
143         2348        Student     Jim
143         2349        Student     Corey
146         2350        Student     Justin
146         2351        Student     Keith
```

And I need to union data from Name column to json array for each Foreign ID  where rows have the same data in Position column. Then this json array should be inserted into Name column of one of row which values were unioned. The result table should looks like:

```
  Foreign_ID | Primary_ID | Position  | Name

     143         2344       Postman     ["Ann","Tim"]
     144         2346       Postman     ["Bob","Dan"]
     143         2348       Student     ["Jim","Corey"]
     146         2350       Student     ["Justin","Keith"]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've found solution, query is

```
MERGE INTO TESTSCHEDULER TS
USING (SELECT Foreign_ID,
  Position,
  MIN(Primary_ID) AS MINID,
  COUNT(*),
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(Name) AS JSONNAME
FROM TESTSCHEDULER
GROUP BY Position,
  Foreign_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) JSONTABLE ON (TS.Position = JSONTABLE.Position AND TS.Foreign_ID = JSONTABLE.Foreign_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET TS.NAME = JSONTABLE.JSONNAME WHERE TS.Primary_ID = JSONTABLE.MINID;

DELETE FROM TESTSCHEDULER WHERE Primary_ID IN (   
SELECT Primary_ID FROM TESTSCHEDULER
INNER JOIN  (SELECT Foreign_ID,
  Position,
  MIN(Primary_ID) AS MINID,
  COUNT(*)
FROM TESTSCHEDULER
GROUP BY Position,  Foreign_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) JSONTABLE
ON TESTSCHEDULER.FOREIGN_ID = JSONTABLE.Foreign_ID 
AND TESTSCHEDULER.Position = JSONTABLE.Position 
AND TESTSCHEDULER.PRIMARY_ID > JSONTABLE.MINID);
```

where `JSON_ARRAYAGG(col)` function works for DB version 12+
... and for version lower than 12.2 alternative JSON_ARRAYAGG is:

```
'[' || replace(rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, '"' || Name || '",')).extract ('//text()'), ','), '&quot;','"') || ']' AS JSONNAME
```

this is for clob column, for varchar use LISTAGG